# Statically typed multi-value result from multi-args method

Tags: c#, arguments, type-safety

I am trying to accomplish the following in C#. However, for brevity I am using functional/Haskell style pseudo-code to make my point.

Imagine a function `exec` that takes any number of arguments. Each argument is a delegate that takes no arguments, and produces some result: `() => T`. `exec` executes all supplied functions and returns their results in a multiple.

```
var results = exec(func1, func2, ..., funcN);
//results will be (res1, res2, ..., resN)
```

If I want to process the results with `process`, how can I be sure that it cannot fail at runtime, due to some mismatch between the input type of my `process` and the result multiple?

```
var process = results@(_, res2, ..., _) => res2;
//this must be typesafe, IFF this compiles:
var finalResult = process(results);
```

**How can I do this?**

*Some extra ideas:*
I can imagine that generics may be helpful, but I am not sure how.
Take e.g. the following code:

```
var results = exec<T:ArgToResultTuple>(func1, func2, ...) // OR
var results = exec<T:ArgToResultTuple>(func[]{func1, func2, ...})
```

This approach could be more extensible then plain overloads, since I'd only need to create a new subclass of `ArgToResultTuple` if I want to accomodate a different number of args/results.

Yet another way is to build a structure like functional lists, but that's inconvenient for the end user:

```
var results = exec(func1, exec(func2, func3));
var process = results@(_, (res2, _)) => res2
//will this be typesafe?:
var finalResult = process(results);
```

Comment: Are all those `() => T` functions returning the same `T` ?

Comment: No, each `funcX` with signature `() => T` can have a different *actual* value for `T`. *That* part of the problem cannot be made typesafe, afaik. I'll need to represent every indiv. result as an `Object`. But I am mostly interested in the result's *structure*

Comment: Well, that would then have to be an `object[]` or `List<object>`.

Comment: Sure, but the drawback is that the length of such a linear structure is not baked into the program, leading to potential runtime errors if my `process` works on the wrong number of values. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: _to potential runtime errors_ - Not directly, both array and the collection classes are subject to CLR memory safety. I don't see the actual problem here.

Comment: imagine that `process` works with `res1`..`res5`. If `results` contains just 4 elements, that will cause a runtime error.

Comment: Of course. `process()` should validate the length of its parameter array. There is no 'magical' way to switch from dynamic/flexible to fully type-safe.